# Improve Performance processing Pandas dataframe (isin)

Tags: python, performance, pandas

My Python script is exiting with OOO memory errors when processing a large file. (Works fine for small subset of records ~10K)

I'm processing 2 files:

- **companies.csv** (File size 19MB) ~43K records
- **competitor_companies.csv** (File size 427MB) ~4.5M records

In file 1, I have a field called **uuid**.

I need to compare:

1. If **company_name** is the same in file1 and file2, copy **uuid** field from file 1 into competitor_companies dataframe.
2. If **website** is the same in file1 and file2 , copy **uuid** field from file 1 into competitor_companies dataframe.

When I process the files in my server (~30 GB RAM), script gets stuck in this line:

```
logging.info('Matching TLD.')
match_tld = competitor_companies.tld.isin(companies.tld)
```

Then script stops and I see this line in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 177106 (company_generat) score 923 or sacrifice child
```

Python code:

```
def MatchCompanies(
    companies: pandas.Dataframe,
    competitor_companies: pandas.Dataframe) -> Optional[Sequence[str]]:
  """Find Competitor companies in companies dataframe and generate a new list.

  Args:
    companies: A dataframe with company information from CSV file.
    competitor_companies: A dataframe with Competitor information from CSV file.

  Returns:
    A sequence of matched companies and their UUID.

  Raises:
    ValueError: No companies found.
  """

  if _IsEmpty(companies):
    raise ValueError('No companies found')
  # Clean up empty fields.
  companies = companies.fillna('')
  logging.info('Found: %d records.', len(competitor_companies))
  competitor_companies = competitor_companies.fillna('')
  # Create a column to define if we found a match or not.
  competitor_companies['match'] = False
  # Add Top Level Domain (tld) column to compare matching companies.
  companies.rename(columns={'website': 'tld'}, inplace=True)
  logging.info('Cleaning up company name.')
  companies.company_name = companies.company_name.apply(_NormalizeText)
  competitor_companies.company_name = competitor_companies.company_name.apply(
      _NormalizeText)
  # Create a new column since AppAnnie already contains TLD in company_url.
  competitor_companies.rename(columns={'company_url': 'tld'}, inplace=True)
  logging.info('Matching TLD.')
  match_tld = competitor_companies.tld.isin(companies.tld)
  logging.info('Matching Company Name.')
  match_company_name = competitor_companies.company_name.isin(
      companies.company_name)
  # Updates match column if TLD or company_name or similar companies matches.
  competitor_companies['match'] = match_tld | match_company_name
  # Extracts UUID for TLD matches.
  logging.info('Extracting UUID')
  merge_tld = competitor_companies.merge(
      companies[['tld', 'uuid']], on='tld', how='left')
  # Extracts UUID for company name matches.
  merge_company_name = competitor_companies.merge(
      companies[['company_name', 'uuid']], on='company_name', how='left')
  # Combines dataframes.
  competitor_companies['uuid'] = merge_tld['uuid'].combine_first(
      merge_company_name['uuid'])
  match_companies = len(competitor_companies[competitor_companies['match']])
  total_companies = len(competitor_companies)
  logging.info('Results found: %d out of %d', match_companies, total_companies)
  competitor_companies.drop('match', axis=1, inplace=True)
  competitor_companies.rename(columns={'tld': 'company_url'}, inplace=True)
  return competitor_companies
```

This is how I read the files:

```
def LoadDataSet(filename: str) -> pandas.Dataframe:
  """Reads CSV file where company information is stored.

  Header information exists in CSV file.

  Args:
    filename: Source CSV file. Header is present in file.

  Returns:
    A pandas dataframe with company information.

  Raises:
     FileError: Unable to read filename.
  """
  with open(filename) as input_file:
    data = input_file.read()
    dataframe = pandas.read_csv(
        io.BytesIO(data), header=0, low_memory=False, memory_map=True)
    return dataframe.where((pandas.notnull(dataframe)), None)
```

Looking for suggestions how to improve my code?

Top command results when running:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                             
190875 myuser   20   0 4000944   2.5g 107532 R 100.7   8.5   5:01.93 company_generat
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling the app to see if you've got a memory leak?

Comment: I haven't yet, but seems to be that Pandas isin function is slow and is consuming most of the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `pd.merge` directly?

You could create two dataframes, one for `company_name` matching, the second for `website` matching and then left merge `competitor_companies` on each of these dataframes.

```
# Create 2 matching tables
c_website = companies[['uuid', 'website']].rename(columns={'uuid': 'uuid_from_website'})
c_name = companies[['uuid', 'company_name']].rename(columns={'uuid': 'uuid_from_name'})

# Merge on each of these tables
result = competitor_companies\
.merge(c_website, how='left', on='website')\
.merge(c_name, how='left', on='company_name')
```

You then need to reconciliate those two values, for instance giving priority to uuid_from_name:

```
result['uuid'] = np.where(res.uuid_from_name.notnull(), res.uuid_from_name, res.uuid_from_website)
del result['uuid_from_name']
del result['uuid_from_website']
```

It should be much faster than using `pd.Series.isin`.